# where should I put a downloaded map in my android project to work offline?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on android studio to develop offline map. I have poor internet access. It is difficult to download the map at runtime. So I want to download  the map first and put it to my project.

Is it possible, and in which folder should I put it?

Comment: It depends on whether you want it packaged as a resource or stored in a separate folder.